# Increasing speed of matching strings in list

Tags: c#, lambda, matching

I have >20MB text files with some lines containing * at some positions. Accordingly should remove from this file positions matched with position containing * (e.g 700670* should cause to remove all positions 70067000000 to 70067099999). First I make list of positions to remove the code is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(List, (pos) =>
{ if (pos.IndexOf("*") != -1)
 { var lineWithStar = pos.Substring(0, pos.IndexOf("*"));
    var result = from single in List 
    where single.Substring(0, lineWithStar.Length) == lineWithStar
    select single;
    listWithPositionsToDel.AddRange(result.Skip(1).ToList());
  }
});
```

It takes ages to get result.

I need to remove line "123456" from input file - everything that matches 123*.

123*

123456

1245

E.g.
Result should look like: 
700204* 
700205100614136* 
700205100662305* 
7002051006623443904 
700205100667271* 
700205120015472* 
Source is: 
700204* 
700205100614136* 
7002041232323234332 
700205100662305* 
7002051006141362332 
7002051006623443904 
700205100667271* 
700205120015472

Comment: how have you read the file?  Im guessing read it to memory? so you're making a second copy also in memory? You would do better  to either read in lines and write out to new file to replace it, and skip writing the ones you dont want, OR a stream which looks through line by line, and then makes note of position of last OK line end.. and then finds where the next relevant data is and overwrites that chunk.

Comment: Got an (small) example of the file?

Comment: Your explanation isn't so clear. Can you show us small part of the file, possible input and expected result ?

Comment: This `single.Substring(0, lineWithStar.Length)` will not change the entire from query. You need to specify a bit more if you want helpfull answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested loop which is influencing your performance. Also you are doing lots of extra string and lists allocations.

I would do this way: go through file once to find all patterns that you need to remove. Then iterate another time and for every line immediately decide if you need to remove that line or keep it. Then you can either create new list with lines you need to keep or write directly to new file or just add items to be removed in separate collection. Something like that

```
var linePatternsToRemove = new List<String>();
var resultList = new ConcurrentBag<String>();
foreach (var line in List)
{
    var asteriskIndex = line.IndexOf("*");
    if (asteriskIndex != -1)
    {
        linePatternsToRemove.Add(line.Substring(0, asteriskIndex));
    }
}

Parallel.ForEach(List, currentLine =>
{
    Boolean needDeleteLine = false;
    foreach (var pattern in linePatternsToRemove)
    {
        if (currentLine.StartsWith(pattern))
        {
            // If line starts with pattern like "700204" it may be the pattern line itself "700204*" and we don't need to delete it
            // or it can be regular line and we like "70020412" and we need to delete it.
            if (currentLine.Length > pattern.Length && currentLine[pattern.Length] != '*')
            {
                needDeleteLine = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!needDeleteLine)
        resultList.Add(currentLine);
});
```

Update: Probably you won't need Parallel.Foreach and plain simple for loop will work fast enough. But if you need parallel, you should think about thread-safe collection for results.

Update2: done changes to code to reflect new information. Please be aware that when using parallel loop, output results collection will be out of order. Also performance will depend a lot on number of patterns in file. If you have big amount of patterns, more complicated solution is required to test every line against lots of various patterns. Probably using trees will be good option for you in that case.

Comment: Use some concurrent collection for this

Comment: @arekzyla, you are absolutely right, thank you. I just quickly copied parts from original code, focused on performance and missed that. Either need to remove parallel or use concurrent collection.

Comment: Thanks for fast respond
Result should look like: 
700204*            
700205100614136*   
700205100662305*   
7002051006623443904
700205100667271*   
700205120015472*   

Source is:
700204*            
700205100614136*   
7002041232323234332
700205100662305*
7002051006141362332   
7002051006623443904
700205100667271*   
700205120015472*

Comment: @LukaszStanulewicz, I've updated my reply. How many pattern lines do you have in that file and what is proportion between regular lines and pattern lines?

Answer (score 0):

I need to remove line "123456" from input file - everything that matches 123*.

```
123*

123456

1245
```

Comment: you should edit the question with this information. this isn't an answer

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49916696/edit) below your post to add this information