# Searching large list for items to remove

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in c# and have problem - there's a large list (text file) with over 1M lines - the structure is:

```
698563200209000258
698563200209000316
698563200225000019
698563200232000143
698563200235000199
698563200235000272
698563200240*     
698563200293*     
698563200301000511
698563200304000849
698563200316000696
698563200328000825
698563200240000833
698563200328000841
698563200328000866
698563200328000882
698563200328000916
698563200328000940
698563200239000957
698563200328000965
698563200239000973
698563200328000981
```

I'm searching for lines in consisting lines with asterisk to make list of items to remove (except those with asterisk)
In example above for line: ;`698563200293*` the result should be: `698563200239000957` and `698563200239000973`

The code for it I've got is:

```
HashSet<string> fileHash = new HashSet<string>(textFile);
List<string> fileListToRemove = new List<string>();
string lineWithAsterisk;

foreach (string i in fileHash)
{ 
     if (i.Contains("*"))
     { 
         lineWithAsterisk = i.Substring(0, i.IndexOf("*"));
         var result = from singleA in fileHash.AsParallel()
                      where singleA.Substring(0, lineWithAsterisk.Length) == lineWithAsterisk
                      select singleA;
         fileListToRemove.AddRange(result.Skip(1).ToList());
    }
}
```

It takes about 1hour to complete (4cores i7) - please help me with speed up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably should use a performance profiler (like [ANTZ](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/index)) and identify the hotspots.

Comment: First: please format your code, is hard to read without any intendation. Second: did you use a profiler to *measure* if and *where* your code is slow? Maybe you´re looking at the complete whrong edge onto that problem. Hard to guess from that little information.

Comment: Can you clarify what lines should get removed?  I'm not following your example

Comment: So for a line that ends with asterisk, you want to remove others which match it?

Comment: If the order in which the lines are put back together doesn't matter, using `Parallel.foreach` might be an option that could be quickly implemented. You can also get all the *-lines first, then split up the whole hashset into x chunks and start a search-and-replace thread for each of the chunks.

Comment: `where singleA.StartsWith(lineWithAsterisk) `

Comment: I am not following your example. The result doesn't make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: Not that this helps any, but here's another post from OP with I believe to be the same file structure:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916696/increasing-speed-of-matching-strings-in-list

Comment: Does all values with asterisk have the same length?

Comment: Exactly Tomas Smagurauskas

Comment: Answering some questions - lines with asterisk don't have the same lenght. The goal is to remove lines matched with lines with asterisk - something like filter - and leave lines with asterisk and lines which don't match those with asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the original code is the fact that you are iterating over the entire data set for each line in the file, resulting in a O(n-squared) complexity.

The following code runs in O(2*n + n log n) time.
Do not forget the `using System.IO;`

```
var textFile = File.ReadAllLines(); // O(n)

List<string> fileLines = new List<string>(textFile);
List<string> fileListToRemove = new List<string>();

// start with dummy line not in file
string lastLineWithAsterisk="************";
int asteriskLocation;

// Sort the file O(n log n)
fileLines.Sort();

// iterate backwards. The * will sort directly after the numbers it matches. 
// O(n)
for (int i=fileLines.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
{ 
     asteriskLocation = fileLines[i].IndexOf('*');
     if(asteriskLocation != -1)
         lastLineWithAsterisk =  fileLines[i].SubStr(0,asteriskLocation);
     else
         if(fileLines[i].StartsWith(lastLineWithAsterisk))
             fileListToRemove.Add(fileLines[i]);
}
```

It is also possible to use a Parallel for loop(each thread would have to have a separate fileListToRemove and combine them at the end.)

Edit:
To solve the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916696/increasing-speed-of-matching-strings-in-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) in sub-minute times use to following code:

```
var textFile = File.ReadAllLines(); // O(n)
var outFile = File.Create("C:\\outputfile.txt");
List<string> fileLines = new List<string>(textFile);


// start with dummy line not in file
string lastLineWithAsterisk="************";
int asteriskLocation;

// Sort the file O(n log n)
fileLines.Sort();

// iterate backwards. The * will sort directly after the numbers it matches. 
// O(n)
for (int i=fileLines.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
{ 
     asteriskLocation = fileLines[i].IndexOf('*');
     if(asteriskLocation != -1)
     { 
       lastLineWithAsterisk=fileLines[i].SubStr(0,asteriskLocation);
     // Write the * lines
     outFile.WriteLine(fileLines[i]);
     }
     else
         // exclude matching lines
         if(!fileLines[i].StartsWith(lastLineWithAsterisk))
             outFile.WriteLine(fileLines[i]);

}
outFile.Close();
outFile.Dispose();
```

In this version Parallelization is not needed since the limiting factor is hard drive speed.

This assumes the output order is irrelevant. Simply reverse the order of the file to get the original order.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Sort your text file and **save it**, we will perform search from the sorted text file. It might takes some time for you to have a new file. The new file might looks like this:

```
698563200209000258
698563200209000316
---some numbers---
698563200239*
698563200239000957
698563200239000973
```

Step 2:

```
string lineWithAsterisk;
foreach (string currentString in fileHash)
{ 
     boolean found=i.Contains("*");
     /*
     alternative, you should try which code performs faster: 
     boolean found=i.charAt(i.Length-1).Equals("*");
     */
     if (found)
     {
         lineWithAsterisk = currentString;
         lineWithAsterisk=lineWithAsterisk.Remove(lineWithAsterisk.Length-1);
         continue;
     }
     if(currentString.StartsWith(lineWithAsterisk))
     {
         fileListToRemove.Add(currentString);
     }
}
```

I haven't tested the code so it might have errors. Please leave a comment if you find any.

Comment: Just note that you cant use a hashset as it is unsorted.

Comment: The code is simply, if found the line with asterisk, then save it in `lineWithAsterisk` variable then proceed to the next line, if not found, compare the current line with the `lineWithAsterisk`, if they have the same pattern, store it in `fileListToRemove`.
Did you try out my code yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since you will only ever be removing the non-asterisk lines, you could simplify this by reading through the file and splitting the lines into two groups - the asterisks lines for matching, and the others which may be removed.

```
var asteriskLines = new HashSet<string>();
var otherLines = new List<string>();
var removeLines = new List<string>();

using (var testFile = new StreamReader("your file path"))
{
    string nextNumber;
    while ((nextNumber = testFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (nextNumber.Contains("*"))
        {
            asteriskLines.Add(nextNumber.Substring(0, nextNumber.IndexOf('*')));
        }
        else
        {
            otherLines.Add(nextNumber);
        }
    }
}

foreach (string testNumber in otherLines)
{
    if (asteriskLines.Any(a => testNumber.StartsWith(a)))
    {
        removeLines.Add(testNumber);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to address memory concerns, you could read through the file once just to build `asteriskLines`, then replacing the `otherLines` foreach with another while loop to read the file line by line again to make the comparison.  You could even output the `removeLines` to another file instead of an in-memory list, if that may also grow large.

**Addendum:**

Using similar system to OP (4 core i7, with SSD) the solution above ran sub-15-minutes.
Making the following updates:

```
var removeLines = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

...

```
Parallel.ForEach(otherLines, (testNumber, state, index) =>
{
    if (asteriskLines.Any(a => testNumber.StartsWith(a, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
    {
        removeLines.Add(testNumber);
    }
});
```

Now it consistently runs under a minute.

(Disclaimer: I don't understand why it was so much faster. But it was. And results remained consistent, though obviously order may be different.)